# SQL counter function by date column?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have data grouped by an ID which stores the date the item should be returned. Is there a way I can incorporate a counting function that will increase as the changes occur?

Example Data

```
id    date_    counter
 1    3/21     1
 1    3/21     1
 1    3/22     2
 1    3/22     2
 1    3/23     3
```

The two methods i've tried is count( distinct date) which will give the value 3 across all rows and a lag function which similarly has been giving me the value 3 across all rows.

```
SELECT t.*,
Sum(CASE WHEN lagged <> date_ then 1 else 0 end) 
Over (ORDER BY id) AS counter --- how can I make this an incremental count?
FROM
(SELECT example.*,
Lag(date_) Over (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_) AS lagged
FROM example)t
ORDER BY date_ ASC
```

Comment: You need to add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` to the SUM to make it Cumulative, without it's a Group Sum in Teradata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/AnJITCtzBRFe2d6kPWmd8Q) function.

```sql
with example as (
  select 1 id, '3/21' date_ union all
  select 1 id, '3/21' date_ union all
  select 1 id, '3/22' date_ union all
  select 1 id, '3/22' date_ union all
  select 1 id, '3/23' date_
)
select *,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date_) counter 
  from example;
```

**Query results**

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | date_ | counter |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | 3/21  |       1 |
|  1 | 3/21  |       1 |
|  1 | 3/22  |       2 |
|  1 | 3/22  |       2 |
|  1 | 3/23  |       3 |
+----+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed thank you. A learning point for those also looking to use dense rank, dense rank's calculated off the order by portion so this should be what the user is looking to count changes for. I had an additional date field which was the date of data entry which i thought needed to be used instead of date_